# View or function '' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a sql script that should check to see if a row exists. If one doesn't exist, I want to create one and if one does exist, I want to update it.

However, in my code below, the INSERT line throws the following error:

> View or function '' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Is there a way to find out what other base tables this would affect and how to achieve my objective?

SQL code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM g4b_stockcountsummary 
               WHERE g4b_stockcountid = @scid AND g4b_protoproductid = @ppid)
BEGIN
    --stock count data doesn't exist for the given product/stock count, create new record
    SET @difference = @count - @expectedtotal

    INSERT INTO g4b_stockcountsummary (g4b_stockcountsummaryid, g4b_stockcountid, g4b_protoproductid, g4b_expectedtotal, g4b_counttotal, g4b_difference)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @scid, @ppid, @expectedtotal, @count, @difference)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --stock count data already exists for the given product/stock count, update record
    DECLARE @originalcount INT

    SET @originalcount = (SELECT g4b_counttotal FROM g4b_stockcountsummary 
                          WHERE g4b_stockcountid = @scid AND g4b_protoproductid = @ppid)
    SET @count = @originalcount + @count
    SET @difference = @count - @expectedtotal

    UPDATE g4b_stockcountsummary
    SET g4b_expectedtotal = @expectedtotal, 
        g4b_counttotal = @count, 
        g4b_difference = @difference
    WHERE g4b_stockcountid = @scid 
      AND g4b_protoproductid = @ppid
END
```

Comment: `g4b_stockcountsummary` is a view.  Please edit your question and show the view.

Comment: You can try with **INSTEAD OF TRIGGER** to write custom update for your base tables.. More info [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/instead-triggers-views)

Comment: I can attest to what @LukaszSzozda said and need to thank him for mentioning that you can in fact define view triggers (amazing times we live in!). Did just that, which was _exactly_ what the doctor ordered in our case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`g4b_stockcountsummary` is a view.  Views *can be* updatable, but only under certain conditions.  These are listed in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) and they start:

> **Updatable Views**
>
> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as
>   long as the following conditions are true:
>
> - Any modifications, including `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements, must reference columns from only one base table.

Hence, you cannot do what you want.  You either need to fix the view or update each base table independently.

I should point out that lad2025 is correct.  You can use an `instead of` trigger on the view to support the `update`.  The documentation is referring to the base update on the view.