# Delete records with duplicates and join in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query (Microsoft SQL Server) to delete duplicates in the table Vehicle that have Vehicle.CarId = Car.CarId and having the same concatenation (CarId, CounterLimit, Kilometers).

Table `Car`:

```
CarId
-----
11111
```

Table `Vehicle`:

```
VehicleId     CarId      CounterLimit     Kilometers   
-----------------------------------------------------
1             11111               250         120000
2             23456               300         150000
3             11111               250         120000 (record duplicated with 1, should be deleted)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: duplicate is defined as having same Carid, CounterLimit and Kilometer or both ?

Comment: Does it matter which `VehicleId` gets deleted?

Comment: Duplicate is defined as (CarId, CounterLimit, Kilometer).

Comment: It does not matter which VehicleId gets deleted

Comment: @JohnSmith can you try the solution below

Comment: Yes, I am going to try the solution

Comment: I used the logic `vehicle.carid,vehicle.CounterLimit, vehicle.Kilometers` as three are same then its a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Joining the table
- creating the rank based on carid,counter limit, kilometer. If all three are same it is considered as duplicate. If you need to add more or less number of columns in this criteria you can adjust this part
- next we take just one of the above row , meaning we eliminate the duplicates using rank_1 = 1

```
with rank as (

select
vehicle.vehicleid,
vehicle.carid,
vehicle.CounterLimit,
vehicle.Kilometers,

row_number() over(partition by vehicle.carid,vehicle.CounterLimit, vehicle.Kilometers order by vehicle.vehicleid) as rank_

from a vehicle
left join car
on Vehicle.CarId =car.carid
)

select * from rank where rank_ = 1
```

Comment: When I try to delete (DELETE FROM rank WHERE rank_1 > 1) I get this error : 
View or function 'rank' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Comment: @JohnSmith read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185999/view-or-function-is-not-updatable-because-the-modification-affects-multiple-b

Comment: Your solution works, you need to add ORDER BY otherwise I get the error "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks for spotting what did you use for order by ?

Comment: ORDER BY vehicle.carid (it does not really matters in my case the order, it is just to run the query without error)

Comment: @JohnSmith yes if you were dealing with dates, then it would matter alot

Comment: You also need to change "as rank_" to "as rank_1"

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks for spotting these , usually i am writing quickly so I miss these tiny detials

Comment: @JohnSmith this is similar to your issue which I answered today as well, would be a good practice for you to check this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077755/oracle-sql-return-column-calculated-from-existing-columns/69077810?noredirect=1#comment122088088_69077810

Answer (score 1):

Delete rows with lesser VehicleId

```
delete v
from Vehicle v
where exists (
       select 1
       from Vehicle v2
       where v2.VehicleId > v.VehicleId 
         and v2.CarId = v.CarId and v2.CounterLimit = v.CounterLimit and v2.Kilometers = v.Kilometers)
```

To just query the table

```
  select max(vehicleid) vehicleid, carid, CounterLimit, Kilometers
  from Vehicle
  group by carid, CounterLimit, Kilometers
```

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . The second solution using `group by` seems like the most sensible to me.