# Oracle SQL return column calculated from existing columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
t1.name, 
(select count(*) from t2 where t2.name = t1.name) X, 
(select count(*) from t3 where t3.name = t1.name) Y
from t1;
```

I have the above SQL query which returns the columns name, X and Y. I would like to return one more column (lets call it Z) which gives the value of X/Y but not too sure how to do this - I tried writing (X/Y) Z but no luck - any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Oracle? As well as a CTE or inline view, in recent versions you can [cross apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024045/266304).

Comment: The version of oracle is 12.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use CTE

```
with data as (

select 
t1.name, 
(select count(*) from t2 where t2.name = t1.name) X, 
(select count(*) from t3 where t3.name = t1.name) Y
from t1
)

select 
data.*,
data.x/data.y as new_calculation
from data
```

Comment: something is wrong with your query , the one with counts

Comment: that is really strange

Comment: does it give you a line number  of the error ?

Comment: If you have other columns/expressions you can't mix those with plain `*`; so you need `select data.*, x/y as ... from data` as the post-CTE query.

Comment: that works in snowflake but thanks for spotting

Comment: @SJ9991 try with data.*

Comment: @SJ9991 I have adjusted the code, does it work now ?

Comment: @SJ9991 no worries, can you accept the answer and upvote so others can use it as well